# Make a query for counting messages to every dialog

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to make a query that will return me a count of messages for every user's dialog. I tried to make it by myself, but it gives me count of messages from all dialogs.
Here is my query that contains params that I need.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM message, dialog 
WHERE (dialog.username LIKE 'acid') 
AND (message.checkms=0) 
AND (message.messender NOT LIKE 'acid') 
AND (dialog.iddialog=message.iddialog)
```

It's result. Pls help!
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `users` ( 
`username` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, 
`enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`surname` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`age` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`weight` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`height` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`sport` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NUlL,
`place` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`photo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8; 

create table dialog
(
`iddialog` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
`reciever` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`username`varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`iddialog`),
foreign key (`username`) references users(`username`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8; 

create table message(
`idmessage` BIGINT not null auto_increment,
`text` varchar(300) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`iddialog` int NOT NULL,
`messender` varchar(50),
`checkms` boolean,
primary key (`idmessage`),
foreign key (`iddialog`) references dialog(`iddialog`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Comment: Get the messages of dialogs of uers then GROUP BY user & dialog then COUNT the messages of each group.

Comment: Your query result shows 1 record returned. Isn't that right for user you queried for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you need to `group by` username:

```
SELECT d.username, COUNT(*)
FROM message m
    join dialog d on m.iddialog = d.iddialog
WHERE d.username = 'acid'
    AND m.checkms=0
    AND m.messender != 'acid'
GROUP BY d.username
```

A couple of quick notes.  It's better to use the more standard ansi `join` syntax.  Also no need to use `like` if you aren't using a wildcard -- it's equivalent to equals without.

---

Your question might need a little more clarification.  Perhaps you need to also group by d.iddialog.  That would return the results per user per dialog:

```
SELECT d.username, d.iddialog, COUNT(*)
FROM message m
    join dialog d on m.iddialog = d.iddialog
WHERE d.username = 'acid'
    AND m.checkms=0
    AND m.messender != 'acid'
GROUP BY d.username, d.iddialog
```